# How can I create a horizontal torus in Minecraft World?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I want to make a Torus in Minecraft - I found the formula on the SK Wiki;

```
//g stone (0.75-sqrt(x^2+y^2))^2+z^2 < 0.25^2
```

This creates a vertical torus, extending the torus in the y plane.

What I want is a horizontal torus, along the ground. I have tried simply making a Torus as is and Flipping/Rotating it, but I am unable to get it into the horizontal plane this way, and unable to modify the formula myself to give me the shape I need.

Answer (score 6):

To change the orientation, just switch `z` with `y` in the equation, as such:

```
//g stone (0.75-sqrt(x^2+z^2))^2+y^2 < 0.25^2
```

Basically, the original equation create a torus around the `z` axis, which gives it a vertical orientation. To make a horizontal torus, we want to put it around the `y` axis, so we put the `y` term where `z` currently is and move `z` around to keep the equation in torus form.

Comment: @Aphrael If this answer solved your problem you should mark it as accepted by clicking green checkmark thingy next to the question